# SSRS hide negative values from scale

Tags: reporting-services, scale, reporting, show-hide

I need to hide specific values from the scale in a line chart.

The report should load from -10 to the automatic Maxim but **Hiding negative values**.

My series are all positive so I can't base my expression on it.

I thought to colour these negative values of white or no colour but I don't know the way to get the current scale value.

Temporarily I checked the "hide first and last labels along this axis" checkbox but it is not the way because It is subject to rescale showing other negative values for example as second element.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If your data is all >0 and you want to start the Axis at -10, what are you wanting to hide? Can you post a sample of your data and an image of your expected output.

Comment: Do you want to draw the axis based on one scale but show a calculated offset. Something like...x scale values start at  -10 but you only want to display an offset on the label of 0 instead of -10?

Comment: I need to make scale start from -10 leaving space on the bottom but without showing any negative value on the scale.
For example a scale can be: {-10 (hidden), -5(hidden), 0, 10, 20, 100, ...(autoscale)}